# How to print json non array data

Tags: php, json

i have JSON data as bellow and want to print "Page" and "PageCount" using php let me know how can i do that.

```
{
    "response": {
        "Page": 1,
        "PageCount": 1,
        "RecordsSent": 1,
        "RecordsFound": 1,
        "Stock": [
            {
                "Colour": "OFF WHITE",
                "Size": "S",
                "Style": "A0000001",
                "Article": "FLORAL 1",
                "Size_Range": "S - 3XL",
                "In_Stock": 58,
                "Demand": 0,
                "Supply": 2,
                "Sell_Price9": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

how can i print "Page" and "PageCount" only?

Comment: You convert the JSON into a PHP array and access the appropriate array elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse it, like this: [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/ZNVVGC69179)

```
<?php

 $json = '{
           "response": {
             "Page": 1,
             "PageCount": 1,
             "RecordsSent": 1,
             "RecordsFound": 1,
             "Stock": [
                       {
                        "Colour": "OFF WHITE",
                        "Size": "S",
                        "Style": "A0000001",
                        "Article": "FLORAL 1",
                        "Size_Range": "S - 3XL",
                        "In_Stock": 58,
                        "Demand": 0,
                        "Supply": 2,
                        "Sell_Price9": 0
                       }
                      ]
           }

          }';

$decoded_json = json_decode($json);

echo "Page: ".$decoded_json->response->Page."<br/>";
echo "Page Count: ".$decoded_json->response->PageCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$content = '{
    "response": {
        "Page": 1,
        "PageCount": 1,
        "RecordsSent": 1,
        "RecordsFound": 1,
        "Stock": [
            {
                "Colour": "OFF WHITE",
                "Size": "S",
                "Style": "A0000001",
                "Article": "FLORAL 1",
                "Size_Range": "S - 3XL",
                "In_Stock": 58,
                "Demand": 0,
                "Supply": 2,
                "Sell_Price9": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}';
$data = json_decode($content, true);

echo "Page:", $data['response']['Page'], "\n";
echo "PageCount:", $data['response']['PageCount'];
```

`json_decode` second param is

> `Assoc` - When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

That means, if assoc = false or not isset, than you have object:

```
echo "Page:", $data->response->Page, "\n";
echo "PageCount:", $data->response->PageCount;
```

Comment: Thank you Vasyl , this method worked for me